# Closing generic visa questions in favour of a resource answer?

Tags: discussion, flagging

So I started to ask a question that I already knew some of the answer to.
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55705/how-can-one-tell-if-one-needs-a-visa-what-type-one-needs (now deleted, so only visible to those with enough rep).
I then noticed that this question basically already exists:
[Is there any online resource that can tell me what visa rules are for passport holders of a specific country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/is-there-any-online-resource-that-can-tell-me-what-visa-rules-are-for-passport-h)

Should we be closing any straightforward (IE "Do I need a visa for X country") questions as duplicates of this? On the one hand, the question isn't exactly a duplicate. On the other, if they read the answers to the "resource" question, then they won't need to ask here for any future journeys.

Answer (score 3):

I'd verge on the side of saying no to closing those as duplicates, since [duplicates are meant more for exact / perfect duplicate questions](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). So while the catchall ["how can I check" question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/is-there-any-online-resource-that-can-tell-me-what-visa-rules-are-for-passport-h) does ultimately provide an answer, it's not a direct duplicate since novice travellers may not be aware of what details need to be filled out to get the correct answer.